# How can I add cc user via flutter client side. (Not using web console)

Tags: flutter, connectycube

I'm trying to use cunnectycube for our flutter(+ firebase) app that is chat application and I want to add audio call function.

How can we add cc user via client app?(or cannot?)
Cuz I want to add cc user by using firebase user(more than 8000)
If we cannot via client app like API, should I add manually one by one?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to create them manually, ConnectyCube Flutter SDK has API for it. Use function [signUp](https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/authentication-and-users?id=user-signup) for it.